# How can I use COUNTIFS for multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, countif

I want to be able to use the COUNTIFS formula for multiple criteria.

For example:

```
1,Banana
2,Orange
1,Banana
2,Orange
```

I want to use COUNTIFS to count how many occurrences of 1 is associated with `banana` and how many times 2 is associated with `orange`.

I'm thinking of `=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,"Banana")+=COUNTIFS(A:A,2,B:B,"Orange")`

This would supposedly equal 4, but I know that formula is wrong and I don't know how to format it.

If this is not possible, then I'd have to use two of the same formulas and add them together, but I'm looking for a better way and just use one formula.

How do I go about this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,"Banana",A:A,2,B:B,"Orange")` returns 0 for some reason, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your formula should be

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,"Banana")+COUNTIFS(A:A,2,B:B,"Orange")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, wasn't sure how the syntax went, but it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try SUMPRODUCT function instead:
=SUMPRODUCT(((B:B="Orange")+(B:B="Banana"))*(A:A=1))

To add additional criteria value, you need to add it to the rest, for example - adding Apples criteria:
=SUMPRODUCT(((B:B="Orange")+(B:B="Banana")+(B:B="Apple"))*(A:A=1))

Similar logic needs to be used to add another criteria range, for example:
=SUMPRODUCT(((B:B="Orange")+(B:B="Banana"))*(A:A=1)*(C:C="X"))

Hope it helped.

EDIT: Just saw question adjustment. In that case you should use following logic:
=SUMPRODUCT((B:B="Orange")*(A:A=1)+(B:B="Banana")*(A:A=2))